# Programmatically set up a VPN server

Tags: windows-vista, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

Trying to do this in code: http://www.askdrtech.com/solutions/post/How-to-create-VPN-Server-in-Windows-Vista.aspx

I've read about DotRas, but I can't find any information about it setting up the server, only connecting to one that is already there.

My application uses multiple clients on separate computers (which will need the VPN when they're using aircards) connecting to a central database, which is installed in the main office.

What I need is for the database installer to automatically tell that server (Preferably Windows Server 2008 R2, but they could be using Vista) to listen for VPN connections and assign a login.

Comment: Just FYI, DotRas doesn't have a server... it's merely a wrapper for the MS RAS client APIs included in Windows. If you were creating a client application that you wanted to use MS VPN to connect to an existing VPN server (Windows Server, Linux, etc) then you'd be able to make use of it to programmatically connect and disconnect.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find a server in there. I'm trying to make this system as user-friendly as possible, and setting up a VPN server alongside the database is part of that. Is there a command line tool, perhaps?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, went with a manual process.